# Offer & Answer from same device iOS in WebRTC

Tags: ios, webrtc, p2p

In Normal Structure, its followed two devices are connected to each other to communicate.

Is it possible to connect same iOS Device to connect itself using WebRTC servers (turn, stun).

What I did So far.

1. Initialized RTCPeerConnectionFactory & setup Peer Connection

   ```
    [_peerConnection offerForConstraints:constraints
                      completionHandler:^(RTCSessionDescription *sdp,
                                          NSError *error) {
                          NSLog(@"My SDP is %@", sdp);
                          NSLog(@"My Error is %@", error);

                          remoteSDP = sdp;

                          [self setLocalLocalDescription:sdp];
                          [self setRemoteRemoteDescription:sdp];

                      }];
   ```
2. I received SDP, I set on local description of _peerConnection's setLocalDescription & _peerConnectionremote's setRemoteDescription
3. I prepared Answer from _peerConnectionremote, and I received SDP, which I set _peerConnectionremote's setLocalDescription & _peerConnection's setRemoteDescription.
4. I set Ice candidate in didGenerateIceCandidate, as

   ```
   if (peerConn == _peerConnection) {
       [_peerConnection addIceCandidate:candidate];
   }else if (peerConn == _peerConnectionremote) {
       [_peerConnectionremote addIceCandidate:candidate];
   }
   ```
5. I receive remote media stream in

   ```
   - (void)peerConnection:(RTCPeerConnection *)peerConn
         didAddStream:(RTCMediaStream *)stream ,
   ```

which I set properly.

In last, It says, state as RTCIceConnectionStateConnected, but nothing happens more.

1. Is it possible, two open two streams at the same time from iOS and connect them via WebRTC.
2. If Yes, how can I separate sources

   RTCMediaStream* stream1 = [_factory mediaStreamWithStreamId:@"ARDAMS"];
   RTCMediaStream* stream2 = [_factoryremote mediaStreamWithStreamId:@"ARDAMS"];

----- For now its stopping first stream even.

Any suggestion or thoughts?

Following this Image as architect, which is working fine with me when one party is remote or other device. But when both parties are same device skipping SIGNALING SERVER, it fails.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. Are you retaining the media streams when they get added in the `peerConnection:didAddStream:` callback? Are you adding the video tracks to a `RTCVideoRenderer`? The way you differentiate the two sources is by the peer connection associated with the stream when `peerConnection:didAddStream` gets called, similar to what you are doing with the ICE candidates

Comment: For now, I am not focusing on two streams, I am sending local video and get peerConnection:didAddStream and adding to the remote. 

PC1 ice candidate to PC2, and vise versa I am adding.

Yes, track which I received from didAddStream, I added to, & also PC1 stream by local resources.

Comment: Are you retaining that remote media stream?

Comment: I fixed the issue in another way. Thanks.

Comment: @VeerSuthar How did you fix it? I'm having the same issue with WebRTC, can you share your solution?